$\kappa$-filtered Ordinal
I'm watching some videos from an online Stable Homotopy Seminar organized Paul Van Koughnett and have a question about definition of so called $\kappa$-filtered ordinal as given in this video, see from 01:50.
The presented definition is: Let $\kappa$ be a cardinal and $\lambda$ a limit ordinal. Then $\lambda$ is called $\kappa$-filtered if for each $S \subseteq \lambda$ and $|S|\leq \kappa$, we have $\sup S \le \lambda$.
I not understand this. Doesn't for ordinals the condition  $S \subseteq \lambda$ already imply $\sup S \le \lambda$ "for free"?
I noticed a similar question, but there one has stonger property $\sup S < \lambda$, which is surely non trivial as we can take $S =\lambda :=\omega$ and $\kappa:=\aleph_1$

Yes, you're right. They must have meant $<\lambda$.

If you're right, it just sounds like $\operatorname{cf}(\lambda) >\kappa$. But I'm inclined by the name to believe the intention is rather $\operatorname{cf}(\lambda)\leq\kappa$ instead.

The usual definition of "$\lambda$ is $\kappa$-filtered" says that, for every $S\subseteq\lambda$ with $|S|<\kappa$, we have $\sup S<\lambda$. In other words, both occurrences of $\leq$ in the presented definition should be $<$. This is equivalent to saying that the cofinality of $\lambda$ is at least $\kappa$.

@Andreas Blass: Could you give a reference for the proof of the equivalence you indicated?

@user267839 I don't know a reference, but the proof is essentially just inspecting the definitions. Both sides of the equivalence amount to "No set of cardinality $<\kappa$ is cofinal in $\lambda$."
